# silent suggest-edit UX failure

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

I tried to submit an edit to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11857393), and on clicking "`Save Edits`", I did not get the usual *your edit is visible only to you until...* thing, so thought something was wrong. I then did it again, just in case someone rejected it quickly. Still got the same issue. I even did a hard refresh, just to make sure, and still... same issue.

<strike>It turns out that my suggested edit was successful, so it was just some glitch somewhere (I use Chrome 24)</strike>. Anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Hmm, what happened to [that suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1442965) though? No reviews, no longer reviewable and not applied...

Comment: Not sure I understand, but by *successful*, I meant that someone approved it.

Comment: Nope, nobody did. I don't see that edit being applied.

Comment: What! Weird. I would bet I saw it was applied some minutes ago (while composing this question). Maybe I was mistaken.

Comment: @Tshepang: It says that the item is [no longer reviewable](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1442965). Normally, it would be approve or reject for a suggested edit on a post that is not deleted.

Comment: Weird, no roll back or any other activity on the question. Looks like a glitch in the code handling the suggested edit itself, e.g. failure to add to the database. Can you try and suggest the edit again so we'll see if it's permanent glitch with that question, or just a temp hiccup that we can ignore?

Comment: @nhahtdh Yeah, but I did not even get any such indication in the UI.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd same issue still.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd though the edit appears here http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1442965.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd in my display, it shows as a new one actually... check the Edit Summary

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd http://imgur.com/RX3BPke